# Starting robocopy as a service

Tags: windows, batch-file, cm

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong because the command runs perfect in the command line but not the file. I also tried doing multiple sources and destinations so I thought that was the problem, but i guess now it's not. Can anybody help me ? I'm lost.

```
::
:: Robocopy Job C:\Users\sean\Documents\startup.rcj
::
:: Created by sean on Thursday, May 25, 2017 at 7:56:19 AM
::

::
:: Source Directory :
::
    /SD:F:\samplesh :: Source Directory.

::
:: Destination Directory :
::
    /DD:D:\samplesh :: Destination Directory.


::
:: Include These Files :
::
    /IF     :: Include Files matching these names
::      *.* :: Include all names (currently - Command Line may override)

::
:: Exclude These Directories :
::
    /XD     :: eXclude Directories matching these names
::          :: eXclude no names (currently - Command Line may override)

::
:: Exclude These Files :
::
    /XF     :: eXclude Files matching these names
::          :: eXclude no names (currently - Command Line may override)
::
:: Copy options :
::
    /DCOPY:D    :: what to COPY for directories (default is /DCOPY:DA).
    /COPY:DT    :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
::
:: Retry Options :
::
    /R:10   :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
    /W:5        :: Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.
::
:: Logging Options :
::
```

is the code...ther service adds just fine but when i try and start it i get an error 1053?

Comment: You're lost and you know what you've tried, imagine our dilemma!

Comment: wow it didnt post my code!

Comment: The usual cause of error 1053 in this sort of situation is that the user has used `sc create` or some equivalent method to create a service that points directly at an ordinary executable such as `robocopy.exe`.  Since `robocopy.exe` does not implement the mandatory service interface, configuring it as a service won't work.  You need to use srvany or nssm (or any of a number of other third-party tools).